# Disable Gutenberg editor for certain page ids

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I need to disable the gutenberg editor on the edit screen of certain pages.

I know how to disable it for post types, like all pages:

```
/************************************************************ */
/* Disable Gutenberg for post type */

add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post_type', 'prefix_disable_gutenberg', 10, 2);
function prefix_disable_gutenberg($current_status, $post_type)
{
    if ( $post_type == 'page' ) return false;
    return $current_status;
}
```

But I only want to disable it for a page, let's say with the ID of "1716".

How can I disable the gutenberg editor for certain page IDs programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible with the `use_block_editor_for_post` hook.

You can do it a variety of ways then with the hook, but here's one example;

modify the excluded_ids array with post_ids that you want edited by the classic-editor.(remember $post is applicable regardless across all post types)

```
function disable_block_editor_for_page_ids( $use_block_editor, $post ) {

    $excluded_ids = array( 2374, 5378, 21091);
    if ( in_array( $post->ID, $excluded_ids ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $use_block_editor;
}
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post', 'disable_block_editor_for_page_ids', 10, 2 );
```

Note that you must have the classic-editor plugin installed for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way:

```
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post', 'disable_gutenberg', 10, 2 );

function disable_gutenberg( $can_edit, $post ) {
    if( $post->ID == '223' ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Gutenberg is disabled when it returns 'false', **223** is page id.
but it can give you some problems if you are using acf. It's better to use it this way.

```
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post', 'disable_gutenberg', 10, 2 );

function disable_gutenberg( $can_edit, $post ) {
    if( $post->post_type == 'page' && $post->ID == '223' ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It uses Gutenberg only on page witch's id is 223. And disables it on all other pages.